# sum squared values in FreqDist, python

Tags: python, nltk

I have python 2.7 code to square the values in a FreqDist (i.e. an NLTK frequency distribution), and the sum all the squares.

For example, from this:

You should get:
2*2 + 1*1 + 1*1 + 1*1 = 7

This works for me, but  I was wondering whether there was a "better" way to do it than this:

```
        for word, frequency in t.freq_dist.iteritems():
            total += frequency*frequency
```

I'm asking because I need to then loop through freq_dist again for something else; right after this code, so I figured it's not good practice to have to loop through it twice if there's a better way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = [2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Using a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
sum(i**2 for i in lst)
```

gives

```
7
```

Alternatively, [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) also works:

```
sum([i**2 for i in lst])
```

If you don't need the squared values for some purpose later, then the generator expression is a better choice as it creates the values only once on demand whereas list comprehension creates the whole list in memory. For more information see this SO question [comparing list comprehension vs generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension).

Comment: Avoid list creation with `sum(i**2 for i in lst)`

Comment: No need for the double parens when the generator is the only argument to a function.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Numpy, you can just square the array:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> values = array([2, 1, 1, 1])
>>> sum(values**2)
7
```

If you're going to be doing any repetitive, heavy computations, I'd suggest you use Numpy. It'll give you huge speed boosts.

Comment: Sadly, there's no array here; NLTK doesn't leverage Numpy as much as it could.

Comment: ... and the question is whether it would be faster because of the memory allocations needed when converting to `np.array`. Besides, if you're going to use Numpy, I'd try `np.dot(values, values)` first.

Answer (score 0):

If the second loop have a dependancy on `total`, no, there's not going to be a better way to do it. If it *don't* have such a dependancy, yes, the better (i.e., faster) way to do it would be to include the work from the other loop inside the current loop. But in reality the speedup should be non-significant.